# Is there a more elegant way to unwrap an Option<Cookie> with a default string?

Tags: rust, option-type

I want to unwrap the cookie or return an empty `&str` when is `None`:

```
let cookie: Option<Cookie> = req.cookie("timezone");

// right, but foolish:
let timezone: String = match cookie {
    Some(t) => t.value().to_string(),
    None => "".into(),
};
```

This is an error:

```
let timezone = cookie.unwrap_or("").value();
```

Comment: You can't call `.value()` on `&str`. The way you are doing it is correct; why do you think it is "foolish"?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or_else

Comment: @anunaki the types have to be compatible for `unwrap_or` to work, so in order to `cookie.unwrap_or(thing)`, `thing` has to be a `Cookie`, not an str. However you could first map `Cookie::value` to get an `Option(&str)` then `unwrap_or`, this way the types are compatible. That is basically what `map_or` / `map_or_else` do in a single step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `unwrap_or_default` plus `map`, what you want is to extract a `String` value, and if it cannot be done just have a default one. Order matters:

```rust
let timezone: String = cookie.map(|c| c.value().to_string()).unwrap_or_default();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f3e0b50865c0b761d27334fa9036f3a1)

Comment: The type annotation wouldn't even be needed here, since `to_string()` doesn't leave any doubt about the return type.